# Rails - passing parameters in link_to to hidden form field for id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, link-to

I've got an application where the user can set up a folder to keep notes in. What I had previously was a hidden form field to store the id of the person who created it, i.e.:

```
<%=f.hidden_field 'user_id', :value => current_user.id %>
```

However, I now need to add a 'keyholder', who has read-only access to this folder. I have a list of links, which only appear if the user has added a folder, or the keyholder can set one up for them.

The keyholder is a regular user themselves, so the above code would only set up a folder with their own id, not that of the person whose account they are accessing. The keyholder has an 'access_id' that matches the user id of the the person whose account they can access.

How do I set it up so that the form is capturing the right user id?

What I'm trying to acheive is the following (this doesn't work, but might give a better idea of what I mean):

```
<% if current_user.access.folder.nil? %>
    <li><%= link_to 'Create a Folder',
        new_folder_path(:user_id => current_user.access_id) %></li>
<% end %>
```

And what would I need to change in the folder form partial to get it to accept this user id? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you keeping a hidden field of user_id? It doesn't seem necessary to me.

Comment: Also, what doesn't work about it? Do you get an error?

Comment: Because the folder needs to have which user it is associated to. The link itself takes me to the right page to set up a folder, but the user_id is set to the user, not the keyholder user who is trying to set it up in the other user's name.

Comment: so are you trying to have the keyholder create a folder for the user they have access to? I thought the keyholder had read-only access to said folder

Comment: They do, but they need to be able to create one too - long story to explain why!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use an authorization gem such like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Comment: I am doing, but don't see how this would help me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i completely understand what you're trying to do, but rather than storing the user id in a hidden field. Just use `<%= current_user.id %>` on any page as it seems your doing.

Then depending on how your models are setup, just create a helper method to check access of the page that the user is on. I'm assuming your helper will check the `params[:id]` or `params[:user_id]` to get the current page.